# Strange Liquibase MySQL connection issue from docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, liquibase

I'm trying to dockerize a Spring project of mine that has the Maven Liquibase plugin and I am facing a strange issue.

Given this Dockerfile for Spring:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
COPY mvnw ./
COPY mvnw.cmd ./
ARG MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=1G"
ENV MAVEN_OPTS="${MAVEN_OPTS}"
RUN mvn clean package
RUN mvn liquibase:update
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xmx1.5G","-XX:MaxPermSize=1G", "-jar","target/api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Liquibase throws the following error:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/dockerapi?autoReconnect=true&serverTimezone=Europe/Bucharest&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true with driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver.  Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

If I use this Dockefile instead:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
COPY mvnw ./
COPY mvnw.cmd ./
ARG MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=1G"
ENV MAVEN_OPTS="${MAVEN_OPTS}"
RUN mvn clean package
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

to start the container, then exec into the container:

If I `ping mysqldb`, the result is successful:

```
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 41ms
```

If I run `mvn:liquibase:update` directly, I get the same error as above:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/dockerapi?autoReconnect=true&serverTimezone=Europe/Bucharest&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true with driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver.  Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

However, if I first run the app (`java -jar target/api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`) or run `mvn test` and only then run `mvn liquibase:update`, the liquibase command will be successful.
It feels like there is something that Liquibase fails to initialise itself and the Spring app can initialise.

I have tried adding `mvn test` to the Dockerfile, however Liquibase throws the same error.

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
COPY mvnw ./
COPY mvnw.cmd ./
ARG MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=1G"
ENV MAVEN_OPTS="${MAVEN_OPTS}"
RUN mvn clean package
RUN mvn test
RUN mvn liquibase:update
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xmx1.5G","-XX:MaxPermSize=1G", "-jar","target/api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Comment: Where is your MySQL database  running? Usually, having a connection string like this `jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306` means that the MySQL database running in a Docker container on the same Docker [network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network/) as the Java application.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi Thanks for your input, yes, both containers run on the same network.